# Discord.js Make your bot wait for reply

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, discord, discord.js

I am a making a bot that when you do !train it says something in announcements and also messages the author and tells him to type finished when he finishes training which then either edits the message where it says training is underway or sends a new message to announcements.

```js
case 'train':
  if (message.member.roles.has('649756129240547348')) {
    const user60 = message.author.username;
    bot.channels.get("649756880314302464").send('<@&673125623463673857>');
    bot.channels.get("649756880314302464").send('Subway Security Trainings!! \n Are you still awaiting tryout? Then come along to this training.\n (Slock in 10-15 minutes)\n https://www.roblox.com/games/4582202027/Subway-Security-Tryout-Centre\n https://discord.gg/bvYgmDe');
    bot.channels.get("649756880314302464").send('Training underway, hosted by ' + user60);
    message.author.send('Tell me when you have finished(say Finished)');
    const collector = new Discord.MessageCollector(message.channel, m => m.author.id === message.author.id, {
      time: 100000
    });
    collector.on('collect', message => {
      if (message.content == 'Finished') {
        bot.channels.get("649756880314302464").send('Training has finished. Hosted by ' + user60);
        message.channel.sendMessage('Thanks!')
      } else if (message.content == 'finished') {
        bot.channels.get("649756880314302464").send('Training has finished. Hosted by ' + user60);
        message.channel.sendMessage('Thanks!')
      }
    })
  } else {
    message.channel.sendMessage('You do not have the permission to do this command')
  }
  break;
```

Comment: No it doesn't, so if anyone knows how to please help. Its all works until it gets to the waiting for the reply

Comment: Formulate your question please more specifically, now it is not very clear what exactly you want and in which place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using [async/await](https://stackabuse.com/python-async-await-tutorial/)